# Sabr practical calibration

Tags: calibration, sabr, cms

What practical methods can be employed to address the calibration challenges of the initial SABR model for very far strikes, particularly in the context of pricing CMS, without over-parameterizing the model, especially when managing a portfolio of interest rate swaptions, CMS, and CMS caps with the goal of hedging smile risk (and also keep getting consistent prices with observed market values) using a single SABR model.